# Spring + JPA in standalone application doesn't save data in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using

- Spring 3.1.1
- JPA 2
- H2
- Hibernate

in standalone Java application. When I run the application, the transaction is executed and when I query the data, the data is retrieved. But the data is not saved when the application is closed.

Please help me.

Here is spring configuration,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sharedEntityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="sling">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.sling.data.Trend</class>
        <class>com.sling.data.Gc</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:sling;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

DAO class,

```
@Repository
public class GcDao {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public GcDao() {
  }

  @Transactional
  public void add(Gc gc){
    em.persist(gc);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<Gc> getGc(){
    String queryText = " from Gc";
    Query query = em.createQuery(queryText);
    return query.getResultList();
  }
}
```

Comment: your question title should be corrected to "Spring" instead of "Sprint"

Comment: DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 in the connection URL is only needed for in-memory databases. Maybe use an absolute path, e.g.: jdbc:h2:/tmp/sling

Comment: I will bet that is something related with the transaction. Ensure you have the values stored in DB once the write transaction finishes. I would suggest you using PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS instead of default REQUIRED for read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you still need to add context:component-scan on your dao package before your tx:anotation-driven element.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sling.dao" />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: I tried the component scan and absolute path. It worked. Thx.